# More efficient way to generate Tkinter buttons in loops

Tags: python, tkinter

I designed a game of Minesweeper where the board was displayed using text, and it worked fine. Using the same pseudocode, I tried to write the game with a GUI using Tkinter, and made a few modifications to account for having a GUI. Here is my code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def create_game_gui():
    for widget in root.slaves():
        widget.destroy()

    for row in range(board_width):
        for column in range(board_height):
            if display_array[row][column]:
                tile_button = tk.Button(root, text=str(data_array[row][column]), height=tile_size, width=tile_size)
                tile_button["state"] = tk.DISABLED
                tile_button.grid(row=row, column=column)
                tile_button.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event, row=row, column=column: quick_uncover(event, row, column))
                tile_button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, row=row, column=column: quick_uncover(event, row, column))
            else:
                if flag_array[row][column]:
                    text = "F"
                else:
                    text = " "
                if data_array[row][column] == -1:
                    tile_button = tk.Button(root, text=text, height=tile_size, width=tile_size, command=game_over)
                elif data_array[row][column] == 0:
                    tile_button = tk.Button(root, text=text, height=tile_size, width=tile_size, command=lambda row=row, column=column: flip_zero(row, column))
                else:
                    tile_button = tk.Button(root, text=text, height=tile_size, width=tile_size, command=lambda row=row, column=column: flip_number(row, column))
                tile_button.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event, row=row, column=column: flag(event, row, column))
                tile_button.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event, row=row, column=column: flag(event, row, column))
                tile_button.grid(row=row, column=column)


def game_over():
    messagebox.showerror("Game Over", "You lost!")
    exit()


def flip_adjacent_zeros(start_row, start_column):
    display_array[start_row][start_column] = True
    for row in range(max(0, start_row - 1), min(board_height - 1, start_row + 1) + 1):
        for column in range(max(0, start_column - 1), min(board_width - 1, start_column + 1) + 1):
            if data_array[row][column] == 0 and not display_array[row][column]:
                flip_adjacent_zeros(row, column)
            display_array[row][column] = True


def flip_zero(start_row, start_column):
    flip_adjacent_zeros(start_row, start_column)
    create_game_gui()


def flip_number(row, column):
    display_array[row][column] = True

    if data_array[row][column] == -1:
        game_over()

    create_game_gui()


def quick_uncover(event, start_row, start_column):
    for row in range(max(0, start_row - 1), min(board_height - 1, start_row + 1) + 1):
        for column in range(max(0, start_column - 1), min(board_width - 1, start_column + 1) + 1):
            if not flag_array[row][column]:
                if data_array[row][column] == -1:
                    game_over()
                elif data_array[row][column] == 0:
                    flip_adjacent_zeros(row, column)
                else:
                    display_array[row][column] = True
    create_game_gui()


def flag(event, row, column):
    if flag_array[row][column]:
        flag_array[row][column] = False
    else:
        flag_array[row][column] = True
    create_game_gui()


def generate_board():
    board = [[0 for x in range(board_width)] for y in range(board_height)]

    generated_mines = 0
    while generated_mines < mines:
        random_row = random.randint(0, board_height - 1)
        random_column = random.randint(0, board_height - 1)

        if board[random_row][random_column] != -1:
            generated_mines += 1
            board[random_row][random_column] = -1

            for row in range(max(0, random_row - 1), min(board_height - 1, random_row + 1) + 1):
                for column in range(max(0, random_column - 1), min(board_width - 1, random_column + 1) + 1):
                    if board[row][column] != -1:
                        board[row][column] += 1

    return board


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Minesweeper")

    board_width = 10
    board_height = 10
    mines = 10

    tile_size = 3

    unopened_safe_tiles = board_width * board_height - mines

    data_array = generate_board()
    display_array = [[False for x in range(board_width)] for y in range(board_height)]
    flag_array = [[False for x in range(board_width)] for y in range(board_height)]

    create_game_gui()

    tk.mainloop()
```

Right now, the code that draws the game state onto the screen is incredibly slow. I can see each individual Button being deleted and placed again. If I change the board size to anything bigger, the game gets very laggy as the game goes on. How can I optimize my program?

Answer (score 1):

### Readability

- place constants at the top of your script with uppercase letters, according to PEP8
- don't exceed the maximum line length of 78 characters, according to PEP8
- add extra white space to align and group variables (it doesn't cost you anything, since python is an interpreted language)

### Shrinking code

- use conditional assignment instead of `if` and `else` blocks

### Efficiency

- just store variables that are used, unlike `unopened_safe_tiles`
- don't create multiple lambda expressions that do the same thing, instead create one and use it for both
- don't look up the same variable multiple times, store it instead. Unlike `data_array[row][column]`
- do not hard code every option, when they are all the same, use a dictionary instead
- **For every click event and button command you call `create_game_gui()` which creates a new layer of buttons on top of the old ones, instead configure existing ones!**